# Blogger: Prevent loading of widgets.js (2015)

Tags: javascript, cookies, widget, blogger

I have a custom website on Blogger, using none of the templates, just regular code. My problem is the widgets.js file. It gets loaded every time, although I don't need it.

The problem is that in the past, it was easy to remove it by replacing the`</body>` tag with `&lt;!&#45;&#45;</body>&#45;&#45;&gt; &lt;/body&gt;`

But now this doesn't work anymore, because of a comment that was added because of Googles cookie policy. This is the code I am getting on the webpage:

```
    <!--<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.jstiming) window.jstiming.load.tick('widgetJsBefore');
    </script>

    <!-- 'Es liegt in Ihrer Verantwortung, Ihre Besucher über die in Ihrem Blog verwendeten Cookies zu informieren. Weitere Informationen finden Sie hier http://www.blogger.com/go/cookiechoices.' -->
    <script src="/js/cookiechoices.js" defer></script>
    <script>
      Code for Bloggers Cookie Information that pops up on every page here
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/2772432204-widgets.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
   Some blogger script here, pretty long so I don't paste it.
    </script>
    </body>--> </body>

    </html>
```

The original intention was to make the whole script tag a comment - but due to the changes in cookie policy Google added this comment, at least on EU sites:

```
<!-- 'Es liegt in Ihrer Verantwortung, Ihre Besucher über die in Ihrem Blog verwendeten Cookies zu informieren. Weitere Informationen finden Sie hier http://www.blogger.com/go/cookiechoices.' -->
```

The problem is - it gets automatically added on blogger and the "-->" blocks the hack from being effective.
What I've tried:

- disabling the cookie notice:

  cookieChoices = {};
- changing the country to not redirect from .com to .de:

  var blog = document.location.hostname;
  var slug = document.location.pathname;
  var ctld = blog.substr(blog.lastIndexOf("."));
  if (ctld != ".com") {
  var ncr = "http://" + blog.substr(0, blog.indexOf("."));
  ncr += ".blogspot.com/ncr" + slug;
  window.location.replace(ncr);
  }

None of it works though. I've search for hours for an answer. Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code `&lt;!--</body>--&gt;&lt;/body&gt;`
It's work fine for me.

Comment: Sadly this no longer works. Anyone got a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or try with this one

```
&lt;!--</body>--&gt;<script>document.write="&lt;/bo"+"dy&gt;";</script>
```